# Apply growth % to range in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm doing a sales forecast and want to project what a 10% growth would be from month 1 to month 24.
For example if month 1 = 100 and a 10% growth for month 24 = 110.

The spreadsheet is laid out like this:

```
        B       C         D              Y
2    Month 1 Month 2  Month 3 ...  Month 24
3     100                              110
```

What function would I use to populate columns C3 though X3? say

Thanks!

Comment: see [FORECAST function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/FORECAST-function-50CA49C9-7B40-4892-94E4-7AD38BBEDA99) or attempt some pre-algebra maths.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it since I don't have the values in row 3 other than the first value

Comment: So let's think about how we could project the growth.  we need to add the interest accrued for that month to the month prior's value.  The interest is 10% over 24 month so if it is straight line then the interest for one month is .1 / 24.  So the formula would be `Month prior value + (Month prior value * (.1 / 24)`.  Which can be simplified to `Month Prior Value * (1 + (.1/24))`.  Or in this case put `=B3*(1 + (0.1/24))` in C3 and copy over.

Comment: keep in mind that the answer from scot is linear... if you need a growth to a percentage (the growth will increase by the same percentage for each step) then you would need something like `old value * (first value / last value) ^ (1/23)` while the 1/23 is due to the 23 steps for the 24 month. this can be simplyfied to `old value * 1.1 ^ (1/23)` which would be for C3 `=B3*1.1^(1/23)` ;)

Comment: @ScottCraner after some thinking, your formula seems wrong... because you will increase each month by a 1/24 of 10%... but `10% * 1/24` would multiply by itself... this way you would get `(0.1/24)^23` which is not `0.1`...  the way you are trying to atempt may be more like `=B3+($B$3*(0.1/23))`... but maybe I got the question wrong :P

Comment: @DirkReichel you are probably correct, I have trouble balancing my own check book.

Comment: I found the 24->23 issue quickly. Thanks guys!